# Quasilinear time algorithm for 3-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability, 3-sat

Is it consistent with the current knowledge that there is an algorithm solving a 3-SAT instance in $n$ clauses in quasilinear time in $n$?

Comment: Note that the question does not ask whether such an algorithm is *known*, only whether we could conclusively disprove that one *could exist*.

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah. Your second question makes sense. But OP is asking if such an algorithm is known. Obviously not since the problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

Comment: I TA'd for an algorithms course where the instructor liked to use this specific phrasing on tests. It tripped up a lot of students who assumed it meant "is there a known algorithm" ot "do we expect to find such an algorithm eventually" but what he was doing with it was testing whether students understood that P vs NP is still an open question that we have not yet proven in either direction. 

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "*consistent* with the current knowledge" is the key here.

For a proposition to be *in*consistent with our current knowledge, there would have to be a contradiction between that proposition and something else that we already know. In other words, we would have to already know a conclusive *disproof* of it.

There are many things "consistent" with our current knowledge that we might still think are probably false. It's consistent with our current knowledge that I will live to be 500. Maybe highly unlikely, given that no human ever has, but who knows what medical advances could be discovered between now and then. I haven't died *yet*, so at the moment we don't have a conclusive disproof of that proposition, and cannot completely rule it out.

So, in choosing your answer to this question, consider carefully:

- Do we have a proof that *no* quasilinear time algorithm for 3-SAT *could ever* exist?
- Or, do we just lack such an algorithm *so far*? Even if we consider that it "almost certainly" doesn't exist, could we still be *tremendously* surprised by a future discovery?

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Since the question looked to me like a school assignment, I've tried to equip you with the tools you need to reason out the answer for yourself, rather than just a "yes" or "no" that might spoil the question for someone who uses a web search to fill in their homework without understanding the answers (not that you would ever do that, but once something is up on a public site like this, it can be used by less scrupulous folks )